# The program skips the printing of the results of the user input when user writes -1

Tags: c#, console

Hi I am writing a program for a school assignment that is suposse to store the input information in an array. When the user writes -1 the program should go to the printing part and print out the results of the input. Its is a basic , enter sales id nr , enter product nr and enter the amount of sold products.

My problem is when the program gets the -1 command, it just turminates and skips the whole printing part, i am very new to programing so this is most likely a easy fix.

Here is the code
Its a console application in microsoft visual written in c#

enter code here

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace _8._20TotalSales2
{
    class Sales
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            decimal[,] sales = new decimal[5, 3];


            Console.WriteLine(" Enter sales staff saleID (1-3) : ");
            Console.WriteLine(" Enter -1 to finish");
            int staff = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            while (staff != -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter product number (1-5) : ");
                int productID = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Enter sales amount of product:");
                decimal amount = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());


                if (staff >= 1 && staff < 4 && productID >= 1 && productID < 6 && amount >= 0)
                    sales[productID - 1, staff - 1] += amount;
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input!");

                Console.WriteLine(" Enter sales staff ID (1-3) : ");
                staff = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            }
            decimal[] salesStaffTotal = new decimal[ 4 ];

            Console.WriteLine("\n {0,10}{1,16}{2,16}{3,16}{4,12}",
                "Product sales", "Sales staff 1", "Sales staff 2", "Sales staff 3", "Total Sales");

            for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
            {

                decimal productTotal = 0M;
                Console.WriteLine("{0,10}", (row + 1));

                for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,16:C}", sales[row, column]);
                    productTotal += sales[row, column];
                }
                Console.WriteLine("{0,12:C}", "Total Product Sales");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0,10}", "Total");

            for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
                Console.WriteLine("{0,16:C}", salesStaffTotal[column]);

            Console.WriteLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It definitly print something (I ran it myself). Not sure if it prints what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is doing what you expect, but the console window is closing before you can see it.

There are two ways to get around this issue.

First, open a console window and run your program from the command line.

Second, if you want it to be able to be run without opening a console window, put `Console.ReadLine();` after your last `Console.WriteLine()` so that the program waits for a return key press before terminating and closing the window.

Comment: Thanks , forgot that xD

Comment: when i ran it it seemed like it stored it all in total sales , you know why? i want the result to show under sales staff 1 , sales staff 2 and so on